# Partial Symbol & Partial Derivatives Formula (Wave Equation)

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

When do you use the partial symbol vs. The normal derivative symbol? For example, I’m trying to write out the derivative of a function f with parts a and b that are respectively dependent on u and v, which are both dependent on x and t. Since a is only dependent on u and b only on v, do I write out the derivative of u with respect to a as a regular derivative, not a partial?

Also, since the function is f(x,t)=a(x+ct) + b(x-ct), do we just write out partial of f with respect to x as starting with the partial of a with respect to u *...
The reason for this question is that the formula for partials is the derivative of f with respect to u*... but I am wondering if here a and b are acting kind of like f, so we just start with a and b in front?

Hope that this question is worded clearly enough! Many thanks.

Comment: What's your question? The equation $f(x,t) = a(x+ct) + b(x-ct)$ comes from the d'Alembert formula to the one dimensional wave equation which looks like $f_{tt} - c^{2}f_{xx} = 0$ with initial conditions $f(x,0) = a(x)$ and $f_{t}(x,0) = b(x)$. Or well you'd have some upper case letters, $f(x,t) = A(x+ct) + B(x-ct)$.

Comment: Thanks - but I’m having some trouble understanding your message, I don’t really read that kind of code yet. Specifically, what I’m wondering is if we can take partial df/dt = da/du*du/dt + db/du*du/dt, because here a and b are like our function f. (Just imagine that some of these notations are partials). I’m also wondering Which of these derivatives are partials, since a depends on only u (is it then a regular derivative, even though u depends on two variables)?